# validating user input

Tags: java, while-loop

I am almost done with this but there are 2 things that are stumping me in my code.
When I query a user for the test score, if the score is not within the 0-100 range, I want to not accept it and then tell them why and ask for another input.
I also want to print the letter grade for their average next to their average score.
For some reason my If logic statement isn't working when I try to check to make sure the score entered is within 0-100.
Also I can't figure out how to get the letter grade to print, but I am not getting any error output so I think that I am on the right track. I think that I could mainly use pointers on my while looping to check for the number being in the range of 0-100.  I would greatly appreciate it.
Here is my code:

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GradeReport 
{
 String name;
 int score1, score2, score3;
 double average;
 String grade;
 public GradeReport()  //creates the first constructor
 {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

  System.out.println ("Enter student's name: ");
  name = sc.nextLine();

  System.out.println ("Enter first grade: "); //try while loops to get grade in between 0-100
    score1 = sc.nextInt();
    while
        (score1 <0 || score1 > 100);
    System.out.println("please enter a grade 0-100"); //checks that score is inclusive 1-100

    System.out.println ("Enter second grade: ");
    score2 = sc.nextInt();
    while
        score2 <0 || score2 > 100;
    System.out.println("please enter a grade 0-100");//checks that score is inclusive 1-100

    System.out.println ("Enter third grade: ");
    score3 = sc.nextInt();
    while
        score3 <0 || score3 >100;
    System.out.println("please enter a grade 0-100");//checks that score is inclusive 1-100
 }
 public GradeReport (String v1, int v2, int v3, int v4)
 {
  name = v1;  //these are to initialize the variables so that I don't get null for the second set of results.
  score1 = v2;
  score2 = v3;
  score3 = v4;
 }
 public void calculateAvg()
 {
  average = (double)((score1 + score2 + score3) / 3.0);


 }
 public String calculateGrade()
 {
  if (average >= 90)
   grade = "A";
  else if (average >= 80)
   grade = "B";
  else if (average >= 70)
   grade = "C";
  else if (average >= 60)
   grade = "D";
  else
   grade = "F";
  return grade;
 }

 public String toString()
 {
  DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.00"); //to format average to 2 decimal places
  String gradeReport = name + "\n " + Double.toString(score1) + "\t" + Double.toString(score2)+ "\t" + Double.toString(score3) + "\n" + fmt.format(average) + grade;
  return gradeReport;
 }

 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  GradeReport gr1 = new GradeReport();
  GradeReport gr2 = new GradeReport("Col Een", 76, 76, 75);
  gr1.calculateAvg();
  gr1.calculateGrade();
  gr2.calculateAvg();
  gr2.calculateGrade();
  System.out.println(gr1);
  System.out.println(gr2);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments...

**indentation**

Please try to be consistent with your indentation style.  It makes your code much easier to read.

**whitespace**

Be careful how you manage your whitespace.  When you read a book or a magazine or a web page, blank spaces are used to separate ideas - paragraphs, sections, etc.  Similarly, empty space should be used to separate your functions, or ideas within functions.  For example:

```
void f1()
{
  do();
  domore();
}


void f2()
{
  doAnotherThing();
  andYetAnother();
}


void f3()
{
  do1();
  do2();

  do3();
  do4();
}
```

Note that it's easy to see that there are 3 separate functions, and the third function has two separate groups of things it's doing - do1() and do2() are separated from do3() and do4() with empty space, visually indicating that there's something similar about do1() and do2(), something else similar about do3() and do4(), and that 1&2 are somehow different from 3&4.

If that doesn't make sense, feel free to ignore :)  (but I would suggest you read a basic visual design book)

**braces**

It's a good idea to get into the habit of using braces around all conditional blocks - it makes it very clear where the block begins and ends.  For example,

```
if(condition)
   line1;
   line2;
```

is different from

```
if(condition)
{
   line1;
   line2;
}
```

In the first case, line1 will execute if and only if the condition is true, but line2 will evaluate no matter what - the indentation is deceiving.  In the second case, both line1 and line2 will execute if and only if the condition is true.

In the first case, the intention is unclear - did the original developer screw up indentation (for the pedantic, ignore languages that use indentation to manage loops)?  Or did s/he forget the braces?  If the first case were written as follows, we'd know the answer:

```
if(condition) {
  line1
}
  line2
```

Of course, if indentation were consistent through the file, the intention of the following code would be clear, as well:

```
if(condition)
  line1
line2
```

**infinite loop**

Note the trailing semicolon that you have on

```
 while
        (score1 <0 || score1 > 100);
```

The trailing semicolon ends the block.  If score1 is invalid, the loop will never exit.

**compilation**

I'm not sure that

```
while
        score2 <0 || score2 > 100;
```

is valid code.  You should place parens around the condition.  You've also got the infinite loop problem with the trailing semicolon, again.

**getting grades**

When you ask for grades, your code currently looks like

```
score = readLine()
while(...)
  System.out.println(...)
```

This means that you read user input, then enter the loop, in which you print a message.  Remember: the loop starts where the `while` starts, so reading input never happens after the first iteration.  You need to read the value the user writes every iteration of the loop.

```
score = readline()
while(score is invalid)
{
   print error
   score = readline()
}
```

**variable naming**

Ignore this section if it doesn't make sense right now - consider it a bad introduction to stuff you'll learn later.

If you have the option, you should always name your variables meaningfully.  The GradeReport constructor has 4 variables, whose purpose is totally unclear if you don't have access to the source code:

```
public GradeReport (String v1, int v2, int v3, int v4)
```

You could use the same name for the variable as the class slot, and you can differentiate with the `this` keyword.  If we first insert `this` for all class variables in the constructor, and leave the rest unchanged, it becomes:

```
 public GradeReport (String v1, int v2, int v3, int v4)
 {
  this.name = v1;  //these are to initialize the variables so that I don't get null for the second set of results.
  this.score1 = v2;
  this.score2 = v3;
  this.score3 = v4;
 }
```

and if we replace v1 with "name"...

```
 public GradeReport (String name, int v2, int v3, int v4)
 {
  this.name = name;  //these are to initialize the variables so that I don't get null for the second set of results.
  this.score1 = v2;
  this.score2 = v3;
  this.score3 = v4;
 }
```

and then replace v2 with score1...

```
 public GradeReport (String name, int score1, int v3, int v4)
 {
  this.name = name;  //these are to initialize the variables so that I don't get null for the second set of results.
  this.score1 = score1;
  this.score2 = v3;
  this.score3 = v4;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you atk. I agree with jball that you did a really good and thorough job explaining all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your code looks uncompilable to me, but that aside, consider the difference between the following three lines of code:

```
while (score1 <0 || score1 > 100)
```

compared to

```
if (score2 <=0)
```

and

```
if (score3 <=0)
```

I think you'll find part of your problem there. For validation, consider the following pattern:

```
do {
  //collect input
} while (something that's false if input is invalid);
```

Comment: Ah. So you suggest using a do while loop instead of a while loop. I am having a hard time with learning looping so thanks for the help. I changed my code above but I think I changed it to something that might be more wrong than it was before.

Comment: The loop shown above is the syntax that you should have in your code, including the `{ }` around the code soliciting user input, and the `( )` around the expression evaluating the input after the `while` keyword at the end of the loop.